# How to reduce ElasticSearch lucene segments without force merge

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

We have a cluster which stores 1.5m records, with a total size of 3.5GB. Every 30 minutes around 2-5k records get updated or created. Up until now after mass indexing the pre-existing data we were force merging to bring the amount of segments down from 30-35 to 1, which greatly increases the performance of the search. After a few days the amount of segments normally rises and levels out at about 7 or 8, and performance is still ok.

The issue with this is we plan to scale our data to around 80GB. If we do so my concern is by using force merge after the initial mass index the segment will be larger than 5GB, at which point it will not be considered for automatic merging by ElasticSearch, and performance will decrease. Without using force merge though I believe the amount of segments will be too high.

Is there a way to force elastic search to more aggressively optimize, without calling the force merge API? We have no users in the evenings or weekends, so ideally we could mass index, and then give it all weekend to optimize the segments to a lower number, with no concern for search performance during that time.